# How to serialize an object using JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to use the JFileChooser to create a dialog box to save my 2 by 2 Array as a serialized object.

This is the code I have used previously to serialize objects and it works fine however, this just generates the file and puts it in the same directory as the program. I want to use the JFileChooser to choose the location of the saved file.

```
private void serializeMap() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("map.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(grid);

    oos.close();
  }
```

So far this is all I have.

```
private void exportMap() {
    KeyboardFocusManager.setCurrentKeyboardFocusManager(new DefaultKeyboardFocusManager());
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("map.txt"));
    fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(gameKeys);
  }
```

Comment: I'm scratching my head over the need for `KeyboardFocusManager`. Maybe start with [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: I'm doing this as part of a game I'm making. I use the keyboard to control the game and to do this I use keyboardFocusManager but while saving the file I need to temporarily go back to the default keyboard focus manager so the user can write the file name. After that I change it back to the game keys.

Comment: I know how to save a File Object using file choosers but I want to save the serialized object. The first code block does this successfully but it just saves it to the source folder and I want to give the user the functionality to choose where the file is saved through the JFileChooser

Comment: Not here specifically, but Object streams are evil and will come back to bite you in the butt.

Comment: *"I know how to save a File Object using file choosers but I want to save the serialized object"* - So - what's the problem then - it seems you already know how to do it. *"I use the keyboard to control the game"* - You shouldn't be using `KeyboardFocusManager` for this, use the [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead\